# How to open a page when connected to a network

Tags: networking, web, ethernet

I have created a network in my office at work and a share file for anyone connected to the network and i was wondering if it was possible to make it so that when someone opens a web browser on the network it automatically opens a HTML document that is kept in the share directory. On the page it is only going to have a few links, like for emails, accounting, website, facebook etc. The actual page will not have anything except links.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, as long as you can browse to the file on the shared drive in a web browser, you should be able to set that as the home page in the web browser so it always loads it up.